# ExtJs - bind a textfield to a record field

Tags: extjs, textfield, extjs4.2, extjs-stores

I would like to bind a textfield to a field in a record in that way that if the value in the record changes, the view automatically updates itself. The view should change transparently, like a grid view changes when the data in the undelying store gets modified.

Is it possible to bind an independent textfield to a record ? Or do I need to implement the `update` event on the store myself ?

Comment: Another idea: did you have a look at [Ext.view.View](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.View). the view is bound to a store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [`loadRecord()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-loadRecord) method to load the record into the textfield but to update it on model changes you need to listen for the `update` event like you said. if you have only one record in that store:

```
var me = this;
store.on('update', function(store, record, operation, modifiedFieldNames, eOpts) {
    me.up('form').loadRecord(record);
}
```

ExtJS 5 (currently in beta) will provide a [ViewModel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html) for direct binding of a model to a view component.